# OpenShift (Cloud) Pod STATUS: Crash Loop Back-off,changing ownership not permitted

Tags: authentication, openshift, roles

I created an application on existent OpenShift project by pulling a docker image from remote repo.
The pod is created but fails with `STATUS "Crash Loop Back-off"`.
Invesitgating the reason using

```
oc log <pod id> -p
```

it appears a list of unsuccessfull `"chown: changing ownership of '...': Operation not permitted`

I found this is due to non predictable user id running the container. 
According to 
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/admin_guide/manage_scc.html and various post here and there,
it seems the solution is to relax security policy:

```
oc login -u system:admin https://<remote openshift endpoint>
oadm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated
```

If this is the solution, I don't know, because I cannot get out of 1st problem:

```
oc login -u system:admin
```

asks for login/pwd and after print an error

```
error: username system:admin is invalid for basic auth
```

I guess there is the need of a certificate, a token, something secure, but I cannot understand how to generate it from Openshift, or
if there was a key pair to generate locally (of which kind) and how to bind the key to the user. Furthermore, checking in the web console
I cannot see that kind of user (system:admin).

Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot,

Lorenzo

Comment: If you login as root to the host machine, the `oc` client is already authenticated as `system:admin`

Comment: Hi Will, thanks. Anyway, when I login, I'm a user with admin role (visible in OpenShift Web Console). 
But in any case I cannot achive the result. 

oadm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated

Apart that is deprecated <myuser> is not allowed to change security permissions. DEPRECATED: The 'oadm' command is deprecated, please use 'oc adm' instead.
Error from server (Forbidden): securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io "anyuid" is forbidden: User "myuser" cannot get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched.

Comment: `admin` and `cluster-admin` are two very different roles. `admin` only gives you permissions within your project. And being able to control `scc` permissions is something that can impact the security of the entire cluster, which is why you're required to be a `cluster-admin` in order to change this setting.

Comment: Are you so kind to suggest how to achive that? Login bycli or web with the right priviledges to run with success oadm policy add-scc-to-group? Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, if you can ssh into the host node as root, you'll be able to accomplish what you're trying to do. If you don't have that access, you'll have to ask whoever is running your cluster of they'll make the change for you.

Comment: Looking at your title "OpenShift (Cloud)"...are you referring to OpenShift Online? Because OpenShift Online does not provide these permissions at all since it's shared hosting.

Comment: Infact Will, I was referring to the online... I need to find another way then to make the docker container run (due to the permission issue). Have you got suggestions on that also? Thanks

Comment: Absolutely! Here's a list of guidelines to refer to when creating Dockerfiles: https://docs.openshift.com/online/creating_images/guidelines.html